# How to download raw (mp3, png) file from bitbucket or github from private repository

Tags: android, ios, github, webserver, bitbucket

I need private file server for iOS application. 
iOS application plays mp3 files for learning foreign language. Names of file are 0001.mp3, 0002.mp3, 0003.mp3 ...
Amount of sounds near 3000.
All sunds size near 400MB.

I can get png or mp3 file from open repository on github but I need loading from private repository.
Can I use github or bitbucket as web file server?

Example of "open" links: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/master/Example/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-40.png

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scottschiller/SoundManager2/master/demo/_mp3/440hz.mp3

Comment: you need to supply your credentials to read files from private repository, thats why the repository is :private: . But using github or other git repositories to host files which your app then downloads when required? I don't think it is the intended use of these services

Comment: It sounds like you want to use GitHub as a general-purpose file server? I urge you to find another solution; GitHub is _not_ a file server, and Git is not a file transfer protocol. Look at CDN providers or something like Amazon S3.